# Как отличить событие восстановления окна от изменения его размеров?

Tags: windows, winapi

Событие WM_SIZE с wParam == SIZE_RESTORED посылается окну при:

- Сворачивании в обычный размер после разворачивания на весь экран.
- Разворачивании окна после сворачивания в панель задач.
- Изменении размеров окна мышью за край окна.

Суть в том, что мне нужно обрабатывать две первые ситуации и игнорировать третью. Есть ли какая-либо возможность различить эти события?

Comment: Да просто запоминай предыдущее состояние... если оно не maximized/minimized, а normal, то это юзер мышом границу таскает.

Comment: О, точно. Спасибо!

Comment: Можно еще покопаться в структуре `WINDOWPLACEMENT` (вызов GetWindowPlacement), сравнить ее состояние перед и после вызова DefWindowProc на это событие, наверняка там что-то фиксируется (флаги или позиция окна).